# Elixir map to proper(unescaped) json

Tags: elixir

How to conver elixir map to normal JSON that I can use in instagram/slack urls?

Doing `Poison.encode!(map)` converts it to something like `"{\"key\":3}"` which gets rejected by api endpoints. Using `IO.puts` fixes the issue but I can't assign result of that to variable (it returns :ok).

So how do I conver elixir map to proper `{"key": "value"}` string that I can use in urls? like this:

`url = "http://example.com/...&variables=#{convertedMap}"`

Comment: Can you post the actual code which doesn't work? You're likely encoding the map _twice_ which is why you get the extra quote and backslashes.

Comment: `Poison.encode! %{"a" => "b"}`
This results in `"{\"a\":\"b\"}"`

Comment: No, that's just how IEx prints it. The value is a string containing `{"a": "b"}`. You can see if you pass it to `IO.puts`. How are you _using_ this value?

Comment: Oh boy, that was it :) thank you !